# Creating Java classes usable as keys for a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have made a class called `Coordinates` which simply holds some `x` and `y` integers. I want to use this as a key for a `HashMap`.

However, I noticed that when you create two different instances of `Coordinates` with the same `x` and `y` values, they are used as different keys by the hash map. That is, you can put two entries even though both of them have the same coordinates.

I have overriden `equals()`:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Coord)) {
        return false;
    }else if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }
    Coord other = (Coord)obj;
    return (x == other.x && y == other.y);
}
```

But the `HashMap` still uses the two instances as if they were different keys. What do I do?

And I know I could use an integer array of two elements instead. But I want to use this class.

Comment: Did you override `hashcode` as well?

Comment: @ZouZou oh no, I didn't know that. I see that it returns an integer. What should I return? Surely it is not the sum of the x and y.

Comment: You need to be consistent. I.e if a equals b then a.hashcode == b.hashcode. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Comment: And it's hashCode() not hashcode().

Comment: I suggest you read the Javadoc for Object which describes what hashCode much do.

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort. Documentation of *equals*: *" Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden..."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override `hashCode`. Java 7 provides a utility method for this.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(x, y);
}
```

Comment: An explanation on why it is required would be nice, but thanks for pointing out this utility class, I did not know about it and it provides some useful methods :)

Comment: From http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html
*When inserting an object into a hastable you use a key. The hash code of this key is calculated, and used to determine where to store the object internally. When you need to lookup an object in a hashtable you also use a key. The hash code of this key is calculated and used to determine where to search for the object.*

Answer (score 4):

You should also override `hashCode()` so that two equal instances have the same `hashCode()`. E.g.:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = x;
    result = 31 * result + y;
    return result;
}
```

Note that it is not strictly required for two instances that are not equal to have different hash codes, but the less collisions you have, the better performance you'll get from you `HashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

A hash map uses the `hashCode` method of objects to determine which bucket to put the object into.
If your object doesn't implement `hashCode`, it inherits the default implementation from `Object`. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)

As such, each object will appear to be distinct.

Note that different objects may return the same `hashCode`.
That's called a *collision*.
When that happens,
then in addition to the `hashCode`,
the hash map implementation will use the `equals` method to determine if two objects are equal.

Note that most IDE offer to generate the `equals` and `hashCode` methods from the fields defined in your class. In fact, IntelliJ encourages to define these two methods at the same time. For good reason. These two methods are intimately related,
and whenever you change one of them, or implement one of them, or override one of them, 
you must review (and most probably change) the other one too.

The methods in this class are 100% generated code (by IntelliJ):

```
class Coord {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Coord coord = (Coord) o;

        if (x != coord.x) return false;
        if (y != coord.y) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = x;
        result = 31 * result + y;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not override the `hashCode` method. Why is that required ? To answer this, you must understand how an hashtable works.

An hashtable is basically an array of linkedlists. Each bucket in the array corresponds to a particular value of `hashCode % numberOfBuckets`. All the objects with the same `hashCode % numberOfBuckets` will be stored within a linkedlist in the associated bucket and will be recognized (during the lookup for instance) basing on their `equals` method. Therefore, the exact specification is `a.hashCode() != b.hashCode() => !a.equals(b)` which is equivalent to `a.equals(b) => a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`.

If you use the default implementation of `hashCode`, which is based on the reference, then two objects that are equal but have a different reference (and so, most probably, a different hashCode) will be stored in a different bucket, resulting in a duplicate key.